# Updating an UserProfile in Djanngo 1.11

Tags: python, django, user-profile, django-1.11

I'm a new developer and I was wondering if you could help me out, updating the values of my ***User/UserProfile*** through an editing form.

I didn't know at the beginning but now I know I could have extended the (default)  ***User*** Model and by doing that avoiding creating a new Model ***UserProfile*** for the profile purpose and making things simpler (e.g. using generic views).

Since I'm still learning I have decided to try a workaround to push myself into thinking instead of asking for a complete solution.

I had already looked for similar questions here and in Django's official documentation, but since I didn't follow a specific recipe, I couldn't find something to fix it properly.

That's what I've got so far:

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = ( 
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Feminino')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username', 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'last_login', 'date_joined'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira seu nome'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira seu sobrenome'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira seu email. Ex: seuemail@gmail.com'}),
            'last_login': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-plaintext rdonly', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            'date_joined': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-plaintext rdonly', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
        }

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'profile_image', 'gender', 'birthday', 'address', 'city', 'country'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'profile_image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': ''}),
            'gender': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'birthday': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira seu endereço completo'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Insira sua cidade. Ex: Recife-PE'}),
            'country': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Informe o país em que vive'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class Profile(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        submitted = False
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            # Getting the Target objects in the DB
            targetuserprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            # Instanciating forms and passing current values
            profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=targetuserprofile)
            user_form = CustomUserForm(instance=request.user)
            user_form.id = request.user.id
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?next=/')
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:  
            submitted = True
        context = {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form,
            'submitted': submitted
        }
        return render(request, "registration/profile.html", context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        submitted = False
        # Creating new forms
        profileform_formclass = UserProfileForm
        userform_formclass = CustomUserForm
        # Getting the values passed throught POST method
        profile_form = profileform_formclass(request.POST, request.FILES)
        user_form = userform_formclass(request.POST)
        # Getting the Target objects in the DB
        targetuserprofile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        targetuser = request.user
        # Validating forms and saving
        if profile_form.is_valid() & user_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            usr = user_form.save(commit=False)
            targetuserprofile.user = targetuser
            targetuserprofile.profile_image = profile.profile_image
            targetuserprofile.gender = profile.gender
            targetuserprofile.birthday = profile.birthday
            targetuserprofile.address = profile.address
            targetuserprofile.city = profile.city
            targetuserprofile.country = profile.country
            targetuserprofile.save()
            targetuser.first_name = usr.first_name
            targetuser.last_name = usr.last_name
            targetuser.email = usr.email
            targetuser.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Erro")
        submitted = True
        context = {
            'submitted': submitted        
        }
        return render(request, "registration/profile.html", context)
```

**profile.html** *(only relevant parts)*

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form.profile_image }}
    {{ user_form.first_name }}
    {{ user_form.last_name }}
    {{ user_form.email }}
    {{ profile_form.gender }}
    {{ profile_form.birthday }}
    <label class="profile_readonly"></label>
    {{ user_form.id }}
    <label class="profile_readonly"></label>
    {{ user_form.last_login }}
    <label class="profile_readonly"></label>
    {{ user_form.date_joined }}
    {{ profile_form.address }}
    {{ profile_form.city }}
    {{ profile_form.country }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

The ***get*** method (***views.py***) is working fine in order to show the current ***User/UserProfile*** values on the form, but the ***post*** one is not updating the values. Maybe is something I'm doing wrong into validating it, since I'm getting the "Error" message from the ***else*** statement. Any ideas how coud I update my ***User/UserProfile*** properly?

Comment: There has to be an action in your **method="POST"** form, like `action="/myview/"` (the last forward slash matters) and that has to match your route in `urls.py`

Comment: I have placed an action pointing to **_"/home/"_** just to test that out, but is still not saving the new values onto the profile.

Comment: Make sure your view actually does something - try function view for the sake of simplicity first, provided it's in urls.py and is listening.

Comment: I've returned to the previous configuration. The form is being send to the right view (the one I'm showing above). But I think there's an error during the validation process, because I've tried many different things and it just doesn't work.